# Http Proxy settings for JAX-WS

Tags: http, proxy, jax-ws

I have a need to set the Http proxy host/port directly on the outbound JAX-WS outbound request (using Java System properties does not work because of WLS container issues).  We ran into a similar issue with Jersey REST, and the workaround looked something like this:

```
proxyConfig = new DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig();
proxyConfig.getProperties()
    .put(DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig.PROPERTY_PROXY_URI, proxyUri);
```

I'm looking for a similar solution for JAX-WS.  Here is its version info:

```
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2.5b02 
 * Generated source version: 2.2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use an HTTP proxy for a JAX-WS request without setting a system-wide property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447127/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-for-a-jax-ws-request-without-setting-a-system-wide-p)