# Unable to generate stubs using wsimport

Tags: spring, soap, spring-ws

I am trying a simple soap consumer using `spring-ws` for the URL `http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl`.

I either get 403 forbidden error for the URL

`wsimport -keep -s ./src -d ./dest http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl`

or

connection timeouts for the URL

`wsimport http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl`

complete error :

> parsing WSDL...
>
> [ERROR] Connection timed out: connect
>
> Failed to read the WSDL document:
>   http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl, because 1) could not
>   find the document; /2) the document could not be read; 3) the root
>   element of the document is not .
>
> [ERROR] Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s):
>
> At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be
>   provided.
>
> Failed to parse the WSDL.

Also tried :

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.orgname.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=9000 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|*.intranet-domain.com" -classpath %JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport -p com.ws.client.pkg http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl
```

errors out saying the `tools.jar` is not found even though it exits.

Comment: Can you access this URL with curl or the browser from the computer?

Comment: yes, I can access the URL

Comment: Are you behind a corparate proxy?

Comment: Maybe I am not sure but how should it matter when am able to access the URL through the browser

Comment: Your browser has the information, that it should access external URLs via the proxy server. If that setting is not done in the wsimport it tries to lookup the domain in the internal DNS which does not know `www.dneonline.com`. If you are working in a company you will certainly have a proxy between you and the target site

Comment: so how can I overcome it any steps in `wsimport` I can try? Got to know we have a proxy.

Comment: I will use a answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are likly to be behind a corporate proxy. Please try to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298699/how-do-i-tell-wsimport-to-use-a-proxy-exception-url) solution to set the proxy for `wsimport`.

Comment: when I run the command I see the erro `Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\lib\tools.jar` even though the jar is exists.

Comment: Please stick to the answer. You should not execute tools.jar, but WsImport.

Comment: Unable to open the link you provided however I also tried `java -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true wsimport -p com.ws.client.pkg http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl` but in vain. I see error `Error: Could not find or load main class wsimport`