# use httpsproxy for selected jaxws request instead of setting it in the system

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, http-proxy

I am using a JAXWS client. I need to use httpproxy for certain selected requests, so I do not want to set it the environment (which will get applied to all requests). I have not been able to find details on how I could set a httproxy for each request.

The best I could find was this post:

[How can I use an HTTP proxy for a JAX-WS request without setting a system-wide property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447127/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-for-a-jax-ws-request-without-setting-a-system-wide-p)

but it is not really detailed and gives little clue. Can anyone help?

Comment: Which JAX-WS runtime are you using? Sun RI? CXF? One from a JavaEE application server?

Answer (score 1):

I find out what custom SSLSocketFactory never been called (jaxws-rt-2.2.10-b140803.1500). Reflection is the only solution to set proxy per service and not using system wide properties.

```
void initClient(BindingProvider bindings, String endpoint) {
  Map<String, Object> context = bindings.getRequestContext();
  context.put(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
  context.put(BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, REQUEST_TIMEOUT);

  Map<String, List<String>> userHeaders = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
  context.put("javax.xml.ws.http.request.headers", userHeaders);

  userHeaders.put("User-Agent", Collections.singletonList("{YOUR-USER-AGENT}"));
  userHeaders.put("Proxy-Athorization",
                  Collections.singletonList("Basic " + "{PROXY-AUTH}"));

  if (bindings instanceof WSBindingProvider) {
    WSBindingProvider wsbinding = (WSBindingProvider) bindings;
    WSPortInfo wsport = wsbinding.getPortInfo();
    EndpointAddress addr = wsport.getEndpointAddress();

    try {
      Field proxy = EndpointAddress.class.getDeclaredField("proxy");
      proxy.setAccessible(true);
      proxy.set(addr, PROXY);

      Field url = EndpointAddress.class.getDeclaredField("url");
      url.setAccessible(true);
      url.set(addr, new URL(new URI(endpoint).toASCIIString()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.warning("Edit EndpointAddress error: " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there isn't a way in the specification - which means you may have to use a proprietary mechanism in your JAX-WS runtime provider.

For example, if your JAX-WS client application is running in IBM's [WebSphere Application Server](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_configwbsclient2webproxy.html), you can set the `https.proxyHost` and `https.proxyPort` properties on the `RequestContext` of the `BindingProvider` (your client):

```
//Set the https.proxyHost as a property on the RequestContext.
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)port;
bp.getRequestContext().put("https.proxyHost", "proxyHost1.ibm.com");
bp.getRequestContext().put("https.proxyPort", "80");
```

If you're using [Metro](https://metro.java.net), the JAX-WS reference implementation, [the documentation](https://metro.java.net/2.1/guide/HTTPS_SSLSocketFactory.html) says it utilizes the JDK's [HttpsURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) to make the client HTTPS request, but offers this tip for providing your own [SSLSocketFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) by setting a custom property on the `RequestContext` of the `BindingProvider`:

```
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = ...; //your implementation that uses a proxy
Map<String, Object> ctxt = ((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext();
ctxt.put(JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sslSocketFactory);
```

If you don't want to use the [JAXWSProperties](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxws/blob/master/jaxws-ri/rt/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/ws/developer/JAXWSProperties.java#L129) constant for the key, you can use its string value:

```
ctxt.put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory",
         sslSocketFactory);
```

Comment: Scotth, I am currently running it on a Tomcat server.
I had given an attempt to the second approach of using SSLSocketFactory but I was not very sure how to create SSLSocketFactory that would use proxy.

SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

How do I make sure that it uses the proxy is what is not clear to me. Can you help on that?

Comment: All my research points to a definitive article on that very topic, but it's rather involved: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077475/core-java/java-tip-111--implement-https-tunneling-with-jsse.html