# Set Proxy Username and Password in java code

Tags: java, proxy

I develop a code to access a SOAP-Server via proxy and regarding to the description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447127/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-for-a-jax-ws-request-without-setting-a-system-wide-p) I can set a global Proxy. Although my question seems Naive but I have not find any guide how to set **Username** and **Password** for this proxy setting in my java code?

Answer (score 2):

you can at runtime get the System's properties and set all what you need to configurate the proxy...

## Example:

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "myProxyURL");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "myProxyPort");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "myUserName");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "myPassword");
```

Comment: Thanks @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ. Please note that I need to change proxy setting back in other parts of the application and I have to work without any Proxy Setting. How can I do this ? 
This properties change the Proxy setting globally in my system.

Answer (score 1):

After some days I found the solution in my case and I try to explain it here.

- It is important to know which kind of SOAP Client service you have wrote. In my case I used CXF 3.1.7 to generate Java code. To be more explicit I had a WSDL file and Generated the code via wsdl2java plugin in maven with the mentioned version.
- In the level of the WebService the follwoing can be done in code to enter the proxy Setting

  ```
  private void setProxySetting(EventPortType port) {
      try{
      Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
      HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
      http.getClient().setProxyServer("***host***");
      http.getClient().setProxyServerPort(80);
      http.getProxyAuthorization().setUserName("***username***");
      http.getProxyAuthorization().setPassword("***password***");
   }catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Please Enter your proxy setting in MyClass class", e);
   }
  }
  ```

  The port is comming from the Service Level that I got like this

  ```
  EventService es = new EventService();
  EventPortType port = es.getEventPort();
  setProxySetting();
  ```